# Escaping a dollar sign in Unix inside the cat command

Tags: bash, shell, unix, escaping, sh

On Ubuntu, I would like to end up with a disk file that reads:

```
foo $(bar)
```

I would like to create this file using the `cat` command, e.g.

```
cat <<EOF > baz.txt
type_magic_incantation_here_that_will_produce_foo_$(bar)
EOF
```

The problem is the dollar sign.  I have tried multiple combinations of backslash, single-quote, and double-quote characters, and cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use regular quoting operators in a here document:

```
$ cat <<HERE
> foo \$(bar)
> HERE
foo $(bar)
```

or you can disable expansion in the entire here document by quoting or escaping the here-doc delimiter:

```
$ cat <<'HERE'  # note single quotes
> foo $(bar)
> HERE
foo $(bar)
```

It doesn't matter whether you use single or double quotes or a backslash escape (`<<\HERE`); they all have the same effect.

Comment: This is helpful, too.  I didn't know these were called "here documents."

Comment: This is the better answer.  I finally figured out that my problem arose because I had *nested* escapes that needed to be prevented.  This is the cleaner solution.

Answer (score 3):

Backslash ('\') works for me. I tried it and here is the output:

```
$ cat <<EOF > tmp.txt
foo \$(abc)
EOF

$ cat tmp.txt 
foo $(abc)
```

I tried it on bash. I'm not sure whether you have to use a different escape character in a different shell.