# Sudo throws error while reading a file post changing the user

Tags: shell, unix, sh

Logging into the shell as a normal user and I am hitting a DB and storing the output to a file. Then within the script and changing into root user(sudo su) and then trying to access the file. But am getting error.

```
pro=$(sqlplus <code goes here>)
echo $pro > pro.txt
chmod 777 pro.txt

sudo su <<Here

cat pro.txt
total=$(cat pro.txt|tr -cd ' \t' | wc -c)
echo $total

i=1
provide=$(cat pro.txt|awk -v var=$i '{print $var}')
```

Output received : 
no output came for "echo $total"
last line get error as "bash: line 10: azure: command not found"

The same script got executed when i didnt get changed to root user.

Comment: Where is the `azure` command?

Comment: @tripleee : I've used 777 just here, code have 755 only. Thanks for that. I am new to unix and please let know the purpose of azure.

Comment: We have no idea. I guess your code is trying to connect to Microsoft's cloud service but there is nothing in your question which reveals where, how, or why this is happening.

Comment: Hi Triplee, its not trying to connect to azure. The file which i read have azure at the second place. It is merely reading the file.

Comment: So broken quoting it is then. I will post an answer and mark this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you are trying to do or where the `azure` text is coming from; but my understanding is that the text comes from the output of the SQL command and then gets evaluated because you are not quoting it properly.

See [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable/27701642) or simply submit your code to http://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human review.

The following attempts to fix the broken quoting, the incorrect permissions, and the multiple [useless `cat`s.](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

```sh
# Don't capture to a variable; simply write directly to a file
# This also coincidentally removes one instance of broken quoting
sqlplus <code goes here> >pro.txt
# Don't use insecure permissions
chmod 644 pro.txt

# Add missing Here terminator at the end; backslash causes code to be run by su
sudo su <<\Here

cat pro.txt
# Avoid useless cat
total=$(tr -cd ' \t' <pro.txt| wc -c)
# Fix quoting
echo "$total"

i=1
# Fix quoting and useless cat
provide=$(awk -v var="$i" '{print $var}' pro.txt)
# Add missing Here terminator
Here
```

This code doesn't do anything useful because the variables will be gone when the `sudo su` subshell exits, so there is probably more work to be done. Perhaps ask a new question where you explain what you hope to *actually* accomplish.

A particularly pesky problem was the lack of quoting around the here document terminator. Without it, the command substitutions would be executed by the current shell. Let me demonstrate:

```sh
sudo su <<Here
echo $(who am i)
Here
```

The output is `you`, not `root`, because the command substitution `$(who am i)` is evaluated by your *current* shell before `sudo su` runs. Quoting or backslashing the string after `<<` disables this expansion, and passes the entire here document verbatim as standard input to `sudo su`.  See also [Escaping a dollar sign in Unix inside the cat command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984960/escaping-a-dollar-sign-in-unix-inside-the-cat-command/21985274#21985274)